# Converting Spark-Sql columns into arrays

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to convert spark.sql.Column into array to carry out different operations. I wanted to know if there is any way in which I can do that using spark java.

Comment: You can use [inbuilt functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) for that

Comment: I've already isolated the column using dataframe.col() function. Now I have to convert it into a Double array. I'm not able to figure it out as to what to use for the same.

Comment: I am not that good in java spark but if you update your code in the question then I can try to help you. Otherwise somebody else will.

Comment: Are you looking for an array of all row values corresponding to a given column?

Comment: You can do something like this ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); mapper.readValue(dataframe.select("colname").toJSON().collectAsList(), TypeReference<<Map<String, Object>(){}).values().toArray();